# Get the current structure entry's order

Tags: templating, count

How can I get the number of a current entry in a structure? In other words, I'm getting the total number of entries like so:

```
{% set count = craft.entries.section('projects').total() %}
<h1>{{ count }}</h1>
```

But, I'd like to be able to output the number of the current entry in the hierarchy, i.e. something like 1/10. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a `for` loop to output the entries you can make use of `loop.index` which will give you the current iteration of the loop (starting from 1) and `loop.length` which is the total number of items in the `for` loop.

So something along the lines of:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('projects') %}
   {{ entry.title }} - {{ loop.index }} / {{ loop.length }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, if you're on a single entry you can use [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/10546/4466) by Marion Newlevant.

Comment: I'm actually needing this in my `_entry.html` file, so it's out side of the the `for` loop. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Just updated my answer with a link to another answer you may find helpful.