# Struggling to get Entry index number so I can output "X of Total Entries"

Tags: entries, pagination, count

I have a channel which has multiple entries in, I'm trying to output the current entry number, for example "**1** out of 20 posts"

Currently this is what I am working with:

```
{% set total = craft.entries().section('spotlights').count() %}
{% set params = {section: 'spotlights', order: 'postDate desc', limit: null} %}
{% set entry_prev = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set entry_next = entry.getNext(params) %}

<section class="page-nav-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-nav">
      {% if entry_prev %}
      <div class="previous-page">
        <a href="{{entry_prev.url}}">Previous</a>
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <div class="previous-page">
        <a class="disabled">Previous</a>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="entry-count">ENTRY NUMBER HERE of {{ total }}</div>
      {% if entry_next %}
      <div class="next-page">
        <a href="{{entry_next.url}}">Next</a>
      </div>
      {% else %}
      <div class="next-page">
        <a class="disabled">Next</a>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have my next and previous links working as well as the total entries in the section, I just can't work out how to get the current entry in the section. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried a few different solutions on here but they all seem to be outdated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this here? https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5125/get-entry-index

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best solution or if it will even work, but this would be my first try.

```
{% for spotlight in craft.entries().section('spotlights').all() %}
  {# Check to see if the title of the "spotlight" matches the current entry's title #}
  {% if spotlight.title == entry.title %}
    <div class="entry-count">{{ loop.index }} of {{ total }}</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```